# Firestore transaction in cloud functions errors of geting data and transaction expired

Tags: firebase, function, google-cloud-firestore, transactions, cloud

I'm trying to create an e-wallet of for school project and new to cloud function and firestore. just a basically money transfers (get and update balance of 2 users) . I tried modify the firestore database directly with no security rules and it works ok. However i would want to later close the database with rules and don't allow user to modify the other's data or their own( only update through cloud function for security) but i'm having problem with writing transaction inside cloud function as in pictures so how can i solve them and is there a way my app can catch the state of callable function like success for failed(sorry for me english, not my native language)

[this is the log with error of i unable to get the balances of user and transaction expired error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8PzM.png)

[this is my transfer functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZT9A.png)

[this is my callable function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoRVJ.png)

[this is my transfer function with direct apprach that runs ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH4uP.png)

[this is my database with collections of users and each have their balance field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27eRX.png)